# Convert JSON object to a string which has no formatting and indentation

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, json.net, portable-class-library

I'm using the Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) package in a Portable Class Library (PCL) project (targetting Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS) and would like to get a string representation of a JSON object with no formatting (i.e. no new lines, no tabs etc). How can I do this?

Currently, if I call `JObject.ToString()` on a `JObject` instance, I get a string with the new line (`\n`) character as follows:

```
"{\n  \"key\": \"value\"\n}"
```

Essentially, what I'd like to do is parse an initial string representation of a JSON object which or may not contain formatting/indentation/etc, convert the parsed JSON object to a string which does *not* contain formatting/indentation/etc, and end with a string something as follows:

```
"{\"key\":\"value\"}"
```

Is this possible with the Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) package in a PCL project? Is there another library I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried the overload of `JObject.ToString()` which accepts a `Formatting` enum value?

```
string json = jObject.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Comment: I only have one `JObject.ToString()` method available to me (which takes no arguments)...

Comment: Hmm, what version of Json.Net are you using?  I just tried creating a portable class library with Json.Net 6.0.3 (the latest) and there is an overload for `JObject.ToString()` with `Formatting` available for me.

Comment: I added it to my project just yesterday. It's version 6.0.3. And definitely no overload of the `ToString()` method available in the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` class. Strange. The summary of the `ToString()` method reads: "Returns the indented JSON for this token".

Comment: Very strange indeed.  Unless I'm looking in the wrong place, the overload is definitely present in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs), and there do not appear to be any conditionals around it which would prevent it from working in a PCL.  I can't think of a reason why you should not be able to see it in your project.  Oh well, it is probably not worth trying to figure it out.  Use the `JsonConvert` method instead.

Comment: Hmmm... Brian, looks like you're right! It definitely is there and I can use it. It just doesn't show up in Xamarin's autocomplete when I type `".ToString"` following my `JObject` instance for some reason??

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I can't find a way to do this with `JObject` but looks it is possible with `JsonConvert`, as follows:

```
string json = "{\n\t\"key\":\"value\"\n}"
var parsedJSon = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (json);
string jsonNoFormatting = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (parsedJSon, Formatting.None);
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do this?...

Comment: Using `JsonConvert` will work just as well as `JObject.Parse()` and `JObject.ToString(Formatting.None)`.  If you can't access the `JObject` way, then go with this instead.  Should be fine.